# From a potential energy equation, how can we determine whether or not the particle undergoes circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

(I realise this may be considered a homework question but I have read the rules.)

I'm working through an introductory book on classical mechanics and there is this question:

Consider a particle of mass $m$ in 2 dimensions ($x$ and $y$). Given that its potential energy is $$V=\frac{1}{2} k(x^2+y^2)$$
for some constant $k$, show that the particle undergoes circular motion during its trajectory and show that all circular orbits have the same period.

So far, I have used
$$F_i (\{x\})= - \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}$$
to show that the equations of motion in the $x$ and $y$ directions are
$$F_x = -kx = m \ddot{x}$$
$$F_y = -ky = m \ddot{y}$$
and equivalently that
$$\ddot{x}=- \frac{k}{m}x$$
$$\ddot{y}=- \frac{k}{m}y$$
I think showing that the acceleration acts in the opposite direction to the position may have something to do with circular motion, but this isn't a sufficient condition and I'm not sure how you show that the particle has to undergo circular motion. What steps need to be taken to show this?

Comment: The particle doesn't always undergo circular motion under that potential. For example, a particle that is initially stationary will simply oscillate along a line going through the origin. The most sensible version of this question would be, "Show that circular orbits _exist_ for this potential, and show that all such circular orbits have the same period."

Comment: Hint: Centripetal acceleration

Comment: Importantly, the trajectory depends on the initial conditions. Only a certain subset of initial conditions (in this case, a choice of $x(0),~y(0),~\dot{x}(0)$, and $\dot{y}(0)$) will lead to circular orbits. So, your question comes down to figuring out which set of initial conditions leads to circular orbits.

Comment: The question as presented here is not well phrased. *"for some constant k, show that the particle undergoes circular motion during **its** trajectory"* The word "its" here is problematic for the implication of a singular trajectory. A better phrasing might be "Find the conditions for which the particle undergoes circular motion, and show that the period is independent of the orbital radius" or something similar.